# mySQL - WHERE, AND/OR selecting

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select all posts from database, (where an ID is = an id from another table, which connects the people i'm in network with) OR (to select posts where i'm the writer of the post.). Actually i'm trying to get posts from people in my network AND my own.

I've found out how to do this, but when using the OR clause it's selecting the rows twice. So for example, if I write a post it's duplicated when echo'ed out from database.

My mySQL:

```
$sId = validate::intValidate($_SESSION['userId']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM networkPost
            INNER JOIN authentication
                ON networkPost.FK_networkYou=authentication.userId
            INNER JOIN network
                ON networkPost.FK_networkYou=network.networkYou
            WHERE networkMe=$sId AND FK_networkYou=networkYou OR networkYou=$sId
            ORDER BY networkPostId DESC";
```

networkYou is: The userId of the post writer.

So how do I select my own posts and my networks posts?

Comment: Can you post your schema as well?

Comment: @Starx Yes, if you would tell me how to write it, not messy into SO? :)

Comment: By schema, i meant show us how your tables are? Posts field, data types, even some sample data wont hurt? Try [sqlfiddle.com](http://www.sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: @Starx I'm trying to create a sqlfiddle, 2 sec :)

Comment: @Starx http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18b07 try this..

Comment: @Starx Hey again. I havent been able to enter SO before now. The fiddle you've given is not what I want. I've found out that it's duplicating the entries when there's more then one person having myself ($sId) in their network.

Comment: Explain me your requirements, very clearly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8829/discussion-between-kolind-and-starx)

Comment: @Starx I've invited you for chat instead :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have few errors in your code

```
validate::intValidate($_SESSION['userId']); //missing square bracket
```

And the `WHERE` part of the query is missing brackets

```
WHERE (networkMe=$sId AND FK_networkYou=networkYou) OR networkYou=$sId
```

Comment: @Kolind, I am kinda confused, about what you are attempting here. See this fidddle [update](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18b07/9) should be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

looks like you are missing `'()'`

```
$sId = validate::intValidate($_SESSION['userId');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM networkPost
            INNER JOIN authentication
                ON networkPost.FK_networkYou=authentication.userId
            INNER JOIN network
                ON networkPost.FK_networkYou=network.networkYou
            WHERE (networkMe=$sId AND FK_networkYou=networkYou) OR networkYou=$sId
            ORDER BY networkPostId DESC";
```

Comment: It's still duplicating the output when I'm using the ()

Comment: can you post some sample data and your expected result?

Comment: What "sample data" would you like to have?

Comment: You should post some data from the each table that you are joining on as well as the expected outcome of the query.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution on my problem. I wanna say thanks to Starx, which I might have pissed off, sorry! I'll make your answer the right one.

But here is my solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT networkPost.*, authentication.* FROM networkPost
            INNER JOIN authentication
                ON networkPost.FK_networkYou=authentication.userId #Så jeg kan skrive hvem posteren er.
            LEFT JOIN network
                ON networkPost.FK_networkYou=network.networkYou
            WHERE networkMe=$sId OR FK_networkYou=$sId
            ORDER BY networkPostId DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$sId = validate::intValidate($_SESSION['userId']);
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM networkPost np,authentication at,network n
            WHERE
                 np.FK_networkYou=n.networkYou AND
                 np.FK_networkYou=at.userId AND
                 np.FK_networkYou in(SELECT DISTINCT np.FK_networkYou FROM networkPost np,authentication at,network n
                          WHERE np.FK_networkYou=n.networkYou AND
                                np.FK_networkYou=at.userId AND
                                (networkMe=$sId AND FK_networkYou=networkYou) OR networkYou=$sId
                                 ORDER BY networkPostId DESC");
```

Comment: @ bluefeet : just see the code first...i didn't use WHERE clause in a single query...second WHERE clause is in inner query...